# How to open .XLS files using shinyApp

Tags: r, excel, xls, shiny

I  have 18 (.XLS) files and I want to use Shiny to open and read them. I am not sure where the problem is. I was able to use this same code to open (.xlsx) files when changed accept = c(".xlsx")

```
install.packages("readxl")
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Use readxls"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose XLS file',
                    accept = c(".XLS")
          )
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('contents'))
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){
      output$contents <- renderTable({
        inFile <- input$file1

        if(is.null(inFile))
          return(NULL)
        file.rename(inFile$datapath,
                    paste(inFile$datapath, ".XLS", sep=""))
        read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, ".XLS", sep=""), 1)
      })
    }
  )
)
```

> Not an excel file
>       Warning: Error in read_fun: Failed to open /var/folders/df/5cr7h6td3432hn68rplrj6lm0000gn/T//RtmpohK8Zl/2f5ccd8bfa3742ad3ec38aef/0.XLS.XLS

1- Why it is not an excel file? I can't seem to recognize this path or folder. The name of the file and the folder are different than what I see in this error

2- Is there a way to open multiple files in a directory?

Comment: It looks like you've pasted ".xls" twice and so "0.xls.xls" is not a file.

Comment: I tried  read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, sep=""), 1) and it didn't work.

Comment: It worked when I change read_excel to read.table()

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

runApp(
    list(
        ui = fluidPage(
            titlePanel("Use readxl"),
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                              accept = c(".xlsx")
                              )
                    ),
                mainPanel(
                    tableOutput('contents'))
                )
            ),
        server = function(input, output){
            output$contents <- renderTable({
                inFile <- input$file1

                if(is.null(inFile))
                    return(NULL)
                file.rename(inFile$datapath,
                          paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""))
                read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""), 1)
            })
        }
        )
    )
```

Comment: It worked with xlsx file. However, the problem was solved  by using read.table()